# TypeError: QTableWidget.setModel() is a private method

Tags: python, database

good evening

im trying to show an .sqlite db [Table] from SqliteStudio in my app. but i cant get it to run
i had changed the ui filed to py before but got told that thats a no go. so i loaded the ui files.
its running so far. but when i press on emloyes im just getting the following error

```
TypeError: QTableWidget.setModel() is a private method
```

```
class MitarbeiterWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MitarbeiterWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("ui/MitarbeiterWindow.ui", self)
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        print("----Mitarbeiterverwaltung geöffnet")
        self.load_mitarbeiter()
        self.mod_mitarbieter = QtSql.QSqlRelationalTableModel()
        self.mod_mitarbieter.setTable("Mitarbeiter")
        self.mod_mitarbieter.select()
        self.table_mitabeiter.setModel(self.mod_mitarbieter)
```

database is open in main part here

```
database = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
database.setDatabaseName("data/database.sqlite")
database.open()
query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
login_window = LoginWindow()
widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(login_window)
widget.setFixedHeight(110)
widget.setFixedWidth(430)
widget.show()
app.exec()
```

showing the table employes [Mitarbeiter] in table_mitarbeiter placed in ui which has loaded from the ui

Comment: the spelling error "self.table_mitabeiter.setmodel(....ö....) has been corrected

Comment: New Error ! ->TypeError: setModel(self, QAbstractItemModel): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PySide6.QtSql.QSqlRelationalTableModel'